# Как получить параметр id из ссылки?

Tags: php

```
$url = "http://site.com/page?id=2";
```

Как получить значение id?

PS смотрел я на похожие вопросы, может не внимательно, но ответа на вопрос не нашел.

Comment: Массив $_GET смотрите. Или я чего-то не того сказал :)

Comment: $url = "http://site.com/page?id=2";
echo $_GET; т.е?

Comment: @emtecif google "php _get"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
php.net/parse_url()   
php.net/parse_str()
```

Comment: то что надо, спасибо

Answer (score 9):

1. Если речь об url по которому открыт документ, то все параметры из запроса лежат в массиве $_GET.
2. Если же речь о строке в переменной `$url`, то используйте функции [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php) и [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php) для извлечения данных:

   ```
   <?php
   $url = "http://site.com/page?id=2";
   parse_str (parse_url ( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $arr);
   print_r($arr);
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, @Ипатьев дал первый подсказку, но и Вам в репу плюс) тоже верно

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match("/.*\?id=(\d+)$/", $url, $output_array)){
    $id = $output_array[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Читать параметры из адресной строки можно, например так:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
echo $id = $_GET['id']; //выведет 2
}
```