# Получить с ссылки имя переменой GET

Tags: php, массивы, if

Есть ссылки с такими окончаниями

```
?w=wall239752675_488

?z=photo239752675_384467374
```

как проверит

если есть `w` то делаем то

если есть `z` то делаем то

Условие понятное дело можно написать с помощью if else
Но как получить с ссылки это `w`и `z` чет ума не проложу.

Comment: `if (isset($_REQUEST['w'])) {...}`, в вашем случае вместо $_REQUEST можно $_GET использовать

Comment: Проверяем ссылку, если в ней есть GET w или z то делаем а если нет то не делаем

Сама ссылка хранится в переменой

Comment: @Анатолий, идите учите основы `php`.

Comment: Раз ссылка в переменной, то это дубликат вопроса: [Как получить параметр id из ссылки?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451088/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80-id-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

Решил свою задачку так

есть урл

```
$url = "https://vk.com/id239752675?w=wall239752675_488";
```

его разбираю и получаю сам запрос GET

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
$qry = $parts['query'];
$var = $qry;
```

Далее с ссылки вернее с w=wall239752675_488 вырезаю все что после знака `=`

```
$test_url = preg_replace("/(=.*)$/", "", $var);
```

А потом уже проверяю

```
if($test_url == "w") { echo "Равна"; } else { echo "Не равна"; }
```

Все спасибо за помощь